# DAX LOOKUPVALUE looking in multiple tables

Tags: dax

I am pretty new to DAX/PowerBI.

I have 3 separate tables, each contains Account Name and Account Number columns.

I already created a 4th table (a derived table of the other 3 tables) showing Account Numbers only once by using DISTINCT/UNION/VALUES. This worked well.

Now I want to bring in Account Name for each unique Account Number onto this 4th table.

I was thinking of using LOOKUPVALUE, but I need it to somehow look up Account Name:

1. in the union of the 3 separate tables' Account Name column
2. in the union of the 3 separate tables' Account Number column
3. per the Account Number shown in this 4th table

Can this be done? I am struggling to write the criteria for 1. and 2.

Comment: I believe you are better of using your original tables and creating relations between them, then in the visuals, you can use all fields from all table, to show distinct, averages, sums, etc.

Comment: I don't think I can create relationships among the 3 tables as on each the Account Name and Account Number information is shown multiple times, so it would result in a many to many relationship.

Comment: Then you create a new tabel, group by distinct and make the relations to the new table